# Не отображается активная точка слайдера в React

Tags: reactjs, dots

Активная точка слайдера - это компонент Dots вообще не отображается, а так же при переключении слайдера через стрелки или саму картинку, код компонента DetailsSlide, в которую передаю компонент Dots:

```
    import { useRef, useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import { register } from "swiper/element/bundle";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
import map from "lodash/map";
import Dots from "../Dots/Dots";
import DetailsButtonLeft from "../Elements/DetailsButtonLeft";
import DetailsButtonRight from "../Elements/DetailsButtonRight";

register();

function DetailsSlide({ swiperDetails }) {
    const swiperElRef = useRef(null);
    const [slidesPerView, setSlidesPerView] = useState(3);
    const matchesMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: "(max-width: 1499px)" });
    const mobile = useMediaQuery({ query: "(max-width: 883px)" });
    const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(1);


    const handlePrev = useCallback(() => {
        if (!swiperElRef.current) return;
        swiperElRef.current.swiper.slidePrev();
    }, []);

    const handleNext = useCallback(() => {
        if (!swiperElRef.current) return;
        swiperElRef.current.swiper.slideNext();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        function handleResize() {
            const display = window.innerWidth;
            if (display >= 1500) {
                setSlidesPerView(3);
            } else if (display >= 883) {
                setSlidesPerView(2);
            } else if (display < 883) {
                setSlidesPerView(1);
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        handleResize();
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);

    const handleSlideChange = useCallback((swiper) => {
        setCurrentIndex(swiper.realIndex + 1);
    }, []);


    //useEffect, который следит за изменением currentIndex 
    //и переключает слайды в соответствии с этим значением.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!swiperElRef.current) return;
        swiperElRef.current.swiper.slideTo(currentIndex - 1);
    }, [currentIndex]);



    return (
        <>
            {matchesMobile ? (<>

                <swiper-container
                    ref={swiperElRef}
                    slides-per-view={slidesPerView}
                    navigation="false"
                    pagination="false"
                    onSlideChange={handleSlideChange}>

                    {swiperDetails.map((teacher, index) => (
                        <swiper-slide key={index} className="details__swiperSlide">
                            <ul className="details__list">
                                <li className="details__list-item">
                                    <img src={teacher.image} alt="картинка" className="details__image" />
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        </swiper-slide>
                    ))}

                </swiper-container>
                {mobile ? (<Dots currentIndex={currentIndex} setCurrentIndex={setCurrentIndex} onSlideChange={handleSlideChange} />) : ("")}
                <div className="news__button details__button">
                    <button onClick={handlePrev} className="details__more-button-katalog"><DetailsButtonLeft /></button>
                    <button onClick={handleNext} className="details__more-button-katalog"><DetailsButtonRight /></button>
                </div>

            </>
            ) : (<>
                <ul className="details__list">
                    {map(swiperDetails, (teacher, index) => (
                        <swiper-slide key={index}>

                            <li className="details__list-item">
                                <img src={teacher.image} alt="картинка" className="details__image" />
                            </li>

                        </swiper-slide>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </>)}
        </>
    );
};

export default DetailsSlide;

{/*
В этом коде мы используем хук useEffect, 
чтобы добавить слушатель события resize на объект window. 
Когда событие resize происходит, мы вызываем функцию 
handleResize, которая определяет количество карточек, 
которые нужно отображать на основе текущего размера окна 
браузера, и устанавливает это значение в состояние slidesPerView. 
Затем мы используем это значение в качестве значения свойства 
slidesPerView для контейнера Swiper. Кроме того, мы вызываем 
handleResize один раз при первом рендере компонента, чтобы установить 
правильное количество карточек. Наконец, мы удаляем слушатель 
события resize при размонтировании компонента с помощью функции, 
возвращаемой из хука useEffect.*/}
```

это сам компонент Dots - точки слайдера, которые должны обновляться автоматически при переключении через стрелки, но активная точка не работает, компонент:

```
import React from "react";

import "./Dots.css";

//компонент точек слайдера, их перебор
function Dots({ currentIndex, setCurrentIndex, onSlideChange }) {

  const moveDot = index => {
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  }


  //Чтобы прописать передачу обработчика события `onSlideChange` 
  //добавленить в список принимаемых 
  //свойств компонента `Dots` и вызывает его при изменении значения 
  //`currentIndex`\.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (onSlideChange) {
      onSlideChange(currentIndex);
    }
  }, [currentIndex, onSlideChange]);

  return (
    <div className="dots__container">
      {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((item, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          onClick={() => moveDot(index + 1)}
          className={currentIndex === index + 1 ? "active" : "dots"}
        ></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Dots
```

стили:

```
.dots__container {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    max-width: 200px;
}

.dots {
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #D9D9D9;
}

.active {
    margin: 20px auto 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #A86E30;
}
```